# Line limit for an output textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, console

I have a textbox output in my application. I would like to add a feature that would start deleting old lines when the textbox reaches a certain limit - say 100 lines. How would I do this?

I am using AppendText and ScrollToEnd methods to update my textbox.

Thanks.

Code: nothing really special here.

xaml -

`<TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="12,6,6,12" x:Name="Output" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1" />`

xaml.cs

```
private void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Output.AppendText(string.Format("{0} --- {1}", DateTime.Now, e.UserState));
    Output.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Multiline Textbox?

Comment: Why do you include the [console] tag? The behaviour your asking for is trivial if you use a listbox instead; why not use a listbox?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: @ Okuma.Scott i guess i just wanted to make a console-like output window, I haven't thought of using a listbox though. But I don't think that I can select text normally in that one?

Comment: @yash just edited it in

Comment: @Algirdyz i posted answer but it is for winforms. Hope you convert it into WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is written for Winform Application but you can use it in wpf applicaton too:-

```
             private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
        int x = lines.Length;
        if(x>100)
        {
           richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines.Skip(x - 100).ToArray();
           richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
           richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, 0);

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps